# SQL Query For Most Popular Combination

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a grocery store application with a table of purchases:

```
customerId int
itemId int
```

Four customers come into the store:

```
Bob buys a banana, lemonade, and a cookie 
Kevin buys a banana, lemonade, and a donut
Sam buys a banana, orange juice, and a cupcake 
Susie buys a banana
```

I am trying to write a query which would return which combinations of items are most popular. In this case, the results of this query should be:

```
banana and lemonade-2
```

I have already written a query which tells me a list of all items which were in a multi-item purchase (we exclude sales of one item - it cannot form a "combination"). It returns:

```
banana - 3
lemonade - 2
cookie - 1
donut - 1
cupcake - 1
orange juice - 1
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT itemId, count( * ) 
FROM grocery_store
INNER JOIN (
SELECT customerId
FROM grocery_store
GROUP BY customerId
HAVING count( itemId ) > 1
)subQuery ON subQuery.customerId = grocery_store.customerId
GROUP BY itemId;
```

Could I get a pointer about how to expand my existing query to get the desired output?

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? There might be proprietrary tricks that can help with this type of relational division problem.

Comment: You are storing Sales info in the table `grocery_store` ? I infer that customerID is used as an ad hoc customer, so it is really just `sales_id` right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select a.itemID, b.itemID, COUNT(*) countForCombination
from grocery_store a
inner join grocery_store b
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and a.itemID < b.itemID
group by a.itemID, b.itemID
order by countForCombination desc
```

Assumed:

**grocery_store** = sales records
**customer_id**    = unique sale

- This query takes all the grocery_store records and for each single sales transaction, it creates all the possible combinations (a.itemid, b.itemid) in a specific order (a.itemid

  This specific order eliminates duplicates (apple, orange) is kept whereas (orange, apple) is not necessary.

  After producing all the combinations from all sales, a simple group by and sorting by count is used to show the most popular combinations at the top

Comment: Actually customer_id identifies the person making the order. There is no unique sales_id in this example (to identify a unique sale). Each row does identify a unique sale, but there is no explicit sales_id number.

Comment: So if a customer buys banana+apple 3 times, is that counted as 3 votes to the combination? There is `NO` unique key to the table?

Comment: Yes, there is no unique key. The only two columns are who bought it (customerId) and what they bought (itemId). If you buy a banana and apple, it creates two rows (one for the banana and one for the apple). Obviously, this means that the same customer couldn't buy a banana twice (but that isn't a problem in the real business problem underlying this sample).