# SQL Query For Longest and Most Popular Combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations

This question is related to this question here:

[SQL Query For Most Popular Combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007485/sql-query-for-most-popular-combination/50411400#50411400)

But what if you have longer lists of transactions and longer popular combinations? If I am right, this solution is for pairs - so 2 items only. I have much more items per transaction and 1 transaction is 1 day:

```
select a.ArticleCode, b.ArticleCode, COUNT(*) countForCombination
from dbo.Outbound a
inner join dbo.Outbound b
on a.ReportDate = b.ReportDate
and a.ArticleCode < b.ArticleCode
group by a.ArticleCode, b.ArticleCode
order by countForCombination desc
```

How can I change this to get the longest most popular combination with Microsoft SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results

Comment: you could add another join to accepted answer for your previeous question for combination of 3, but in general I think pure sql is not the best solution here..